# From JSON to grouped ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON var with example data

```
var data = { "destinations":[

    {
            "Hotel":"Hotel Waldorf",
            "Country":"BR",
            "Continent":"South America",
            "City": "City",
            "Link" : ""                 
        },

    {
            "Hotel":"Hilton",
            "Country":"CR",
            "Continent":"Middle America",
            "City": "San Jose",
            "Link" : ""                 
        },

    {
            "Hotel":"Park Inn",
            "Country":"DE",
            "Continent":"Europe",
            "City": "Berlin",
            "Link" : "http://www.typo3.org"                 
        },

    {
            "Hotel":"Michelsberger",
            "Country":"DE",
            "Continent":"Europe",
            "City": "Berlin",
            "Link" : "http://www.berlin.de"                 
        }

]}
```

I want an ul grouped by continents with countries in sub ul like

```
<ul>
  <li>Europe
    <ul>
      <li>Deutschland</li>
      <li>....</li>
    </ul>
   ...
   </li>
```

My idea was to create a second level array, but I can`t create the countries-level. Reading continents works fine, but if i push a country to the array, i got an the error "push to undefined"
This is my function:
Any ideas or other ways?
    function getCountries() {
    var countryList = "";
    var continents = new Array();

```
for (var i in data.destinations) {
    if ( $.inArray(data.destinations[i].Continent , continents) == -1) {
        continents.push(data.destinations[i].Continent);
    } else {

    }
}

continents.sort();
for (var j in continents) {
    countryList += "<li>"+continents[j]+"</li>";
}
countryList += "</ul>";
$('#js--fx--country-list').html(countryList);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding countries anywhere.
Check fiddle: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/cmbgeb2k/)

Your script may look like follows (I commented out some code):

```
function getCountries() { 

    var continents = [],
    //countryList = '',
    continentsObj = {},
    html = '',
    continent,
    country;

for (var i in data.destinations) {
    //if ( $.inArray(data.destinations[i].Continent , continents) == -1) {
    // continents.push(data.destinations[i].Continent);


    // check if continent exists
    continent = data.destinations[i].Continent;
    if (!continentsObj[ continent ]) {
        continentsObj[ continent ] = [];
        // also add to smiple array to sort later
        continents.push(continent);
    }

    // check if country exists
    country = data.destinations[i].Country;
    if ( continentsObj[ continent ].indexOf( country ) === -1 ) {
        continentsObj[ continent ].push( country );
    }  
}

continents.sort();

html += '<ul>';
for (var i=0, lenI=continents.length; i<lenI; i++) {
    continent = continents[i];
    html += '<li>'+continent;
    html += '<ul>';
    for (var y=0, len = continentsObj[ continent ].length; y<len; y++) {
        html += '<li>'+continentsObj[ continent ][y]+'</li>';
    }
    html += '</ul>';
    html +='</li>';
}
html += '</ul>';

$('#js--fx--country-list').html( html );
}
```